# Recursive category and inner join

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, inner-join

I want to make recursive category menu for product categories on my web page.Each category must retrieve related first item according to CategoryId on "Product" table but this category should be disappear if category hasn't any product.Actually, i can make to easily with using INNER JOIN for non-recursive category menu.How can i solve this issue?Is there any idea?

I can use a method as follow but this method both amateur and may be null first item.

**Category table**

```
+--------------+---------------+------------+
|  CategoryId  | CategoryName  | ParentId   |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
|      1       | Cookware      |   NULL     |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
|      2       | Tableware     |   NULL     |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
|      3       | Teapots       |     1      |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
|      4       | Cutleries     |     3      |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
|      5       | 30pcs Cutlery |     2      |
+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

**Product table**

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------------+------------+
|  ProductId   | ProductCode  | ProductName        | CategoryId |
+--------------+--------------+--------------------+------------+
|       1      |   G110090    |   Teapot           |      3     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------------+------------+
|       2      |   D220623    |   Cutlery Set      |      5     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------------+------------+
```

**RecursiveCategory method**

```
public string RecursiveCategory(IEnumerable<Category> category, int? parent)
{
    string catNode = string.Empty;
    if(category.Any(n=>n.ParentId == parent))
    {
        catNode += "<ul>";
            foreach(Category c in category)
            {
                catNode += "<li>";
                catNode += "<a href='/Detail/" + GetFirstItem(c.CategoryId).ProductId + "'>"+c.CategoryName+"</a>";
                catNode += RecursiveCategory(category, c.ParentId);
                catNode += "</li>";
            }
        catNode += "</ul>"
    }
    return catNode;
}
```

**GetFirstItem method**

```
public Product GetFirstItem(int categoryId)
{
    Product prod = new Product();
    foreach(Product p in db.Product.Where(n=>n.CategoryId == categoryId))
    {
        prod.ProductId = p.ProductId;
        prod.ProductName = p.ProductName;
        ...
    }
    return prod;
}
```

Comment: You say that "category must retrieve related first item according to CategoryId on Product" and "this category should be disappear if category hasn't any product". How could it retive first item if it hasnt any product?

Comment: @voo, i think my question some mistaken because main categories may be null.

Comment: i am going to try solution that written by Jorge Córdoba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to construct a hierarchy from a given point (using null in the first call will give you the full tree with the products for each category). As a modification you could make product lazy load if you need to:

```
public class Category
{
  IEnumerable<Category> Children {get;set;}
  IEnumerable<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategory(int? parent)
{
  var result = new List<Category>();
  foreach (var cat in categories.Where(p => p.parentId = parent)
  {
     var generatedCategory = new Category();
     generatedCategory.Children = GetCategory(cat.id);
     generatedCategory.Products = products.Where(p => p.CategoryId = cat.CategoryId);
     result.Add(generatedCategory);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the code just a guide about how to construct it easily.